# What is the best algorithm to determine whether an $n \times n$ matrix is ​invertible or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

I want to find the best algorithm to determine if an $n \times n$ matrix is ​​invertible in high dimensions...

Is the best way to determine the invertibility of a matrix is ​​to calculate the determinant of that matrix?
If the determinant is $0$, then it is not invertible, and if it is non-zero, then it is invertible... right?
I also found a theorem that I did not understand how to use it:

An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if it is row equivalent to the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I$.

Comment: The determinant works, but then what is the best algorithm to compute the determinant? If you are not worried about numerical issues arising from floating-point on computers, then Gaussian elimination is fine. If you are, then something more numerically stable like singular value decomposition might be more appropriate.